# Bash mapfile array count different

Tags: bash

I did the following:

```bash
mapfile -t array < <(commands)
```

where `commands` will produce new-line separated output.

Then based on the result, if there's nothing in the array, exit, otherwise continue:

```bash
[[ "${#array[@]}" -eq 0 ]] && exit

...
```

The problem is that the condition is never met. Because when the said `commands` returns nothing, the `${#array[@]}` returns 1 instead of 0.

But it counts correctly if I assign the array as follows:

```
array=($(commands))
```

My tests:

```bash
$ declare -a array
$ array=($(echo))
$ echo ${#array[@]}
0
$ unset array
$ mapfile -t array < <(echo)
$ echo ${#array[@]}
1
```

Why?

---

Initially I used the `array=($(commands))` format but `shellcheck` suggested me to use `mapfile` instead.

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: There's a newline in the input to `mapfile` in `mapfile -t array < <(echo)`. It's not *nothing* - compare with the output of, say, `true` or `:`.

Comment: The behavior you describe indicates the `commands` don't output newline-separated lines.  So this comes down to those particular commands.  Without them, we can't help you solve this issue.

Comment: Check if first element is empty: `[[ "${array[0]}" == "" ]] && exit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you get if the command inside the prints nothing:

```
$ mapfile -t array < <(printf ''); echo "num: ${#array[@]}"; declare -p array
num: 0
declare -a array=()
```

This is what you get if it prints a single empty line:

```
$ mapfile -t array < <(echo); echo "num: ${#array[@]}"; declare -p array
num: 1
declare -a array=([0]="")
```

The empty line produces an empty element, quite appropriately.

If your program produces such empty lines and you can't stop it, you could remove them with e.g. `grep`. Or check for the case of a single array element that's empty.

Remove the empty lines with `grep`:

```
$ mapfile -t array < <(echo | grep .); echo "num: ${#array[@]}"; declare -p array
num: 0
declare -a array=()
```

Check for the empty element:

```
$ mapfile -t array < <(echo);
$ if [[ "${#array[@]}" = 0 || "${#array[@]}" = 1 && "${array[0]}" = "" ]]; then 
    echo "empty list or only one empty element"; 
 fi
empty list or only one empty element
```

In

```
array=($(commands))
```

it's different, since the result of the command substitution goes through word splitting, which also removes any trailing whitespace. And splits lines with whitespace in them. (The command substitution itself also removes any trailing newlines, not that it matters here.)

Comment: The `declare -p array` is very useful.

Comment: @annahri, it is! Just note that there's an annoying difference between how `declare -p` prints regular variables vs. arrays. With arrays, it uses the `$''` format, so e.g. a line with a newline looks like `$'foo\n'`. But with scalars, it prints a raw newline instead, making the output span two lines. And of course there's the usual backslash-escaping of special characters, which makes the output unambiguous but seems to confuse those who aren't familiar with it sometimes.